# El controlador no me retorna a la View - ASP.NET MVC

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc

En mi `View userListarLibros.cshtml` con `Ajax` estoy pasando un `array` al `controlador`. Y este mismo debería dirigirme a la`View Comprar.cshtml`, pero no lo hace!.¿Por que pasa esto?.

aca `Ajax`

```js
 function comprar() {

        var uri = '@Url.Action("Comprar", "Usser")';
        var ides = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('arrayId'));

        //compruebo array vacio
        if (ides == null)
        {
            alert("Debe elegir un libro para poder comprar!.")
        }
        else
        {
            $.ajax({
                url: uri,
                data: JSON.stringify(ides),
                type: 'POST',
                contentType: 'application/json',
                success: function (hola) {
                    console.log(hola);
                }
                
            });
        }
    }
```

Aca el controlador

```html
  public ActionResult Comprar(int[] data)
        {
                      
            return View();
        }
```

Comment: Como se llama el Controlador donde tienes la Acción `Comprar()`?

Comment: ¿Qué tienes en la Vista?

Comment: Hola @Rafael Acosta,  public ActionResult Comprar(int[] data) esta en el controlador UsserController

Comment: Hola @fredyfx! por el momento en la vista Comprar.cshtml solo tengo un titulo, mi idea va a hacer pasarle una Lista a la View Comprar, en un post anterior me ayudaste, pero la solución que me diste fue traer el contenido de la View Comprar a la view userListarLibros.cshtml. Yo quiero que se dirige a la view Comprar y se quede parado en esta misma.

Comment: ¿Y si lo mandas en un formulario simple? Creo que estás complicando un poco las cosas, por otro lado te sugiero ver el workshop que hice tiempo atrás, está basado en un curso de varias horas de la MVA de Microsoft y experiencias del campo laboral.